# How to put a string search with grep command into if statement?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, ksh

I want to search multiple strings in two files. 
If one string is found in both files, then make something.
If one string is found in only one file, then make another thing.

My commands are the next:

```
####This is for the affirmative sentence in both files
if grep -qw "$users" "$file1" && grep -qw "$users" "$file2"; then

####This is for the affirmative sentence in only one file, and negative for the other one
if grep -qw "$users" "$file1" ! grep -qw "$users" "$file2"; then
```

is it a correct the way to deny and affirm the statements?
p.d. I'm using KSH shell.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
if grep -wq -- "$user" "$file1" && grep -wq -- "$user" "$file2" ; then
   echo "string avail in both files"
elif grep -wq -- "$user" "$file1" "$file2"; then
   echo "string avail in only one file"
fi
```

- `grep`  can search for patterns in multiple files, so no need to use an OR/NOT operator.

Comment: Is there a minimal difference between the "-wq" and the "-qw" in any each command?

Comment: No, both of them provide the -q and -w options to grep.

Comment: Why no quotes on the variable expansion?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble is it correctly: "$user" "$file1"?

Comment: @Mareyes yes that is correct

Answer (score 13):

Another option:

```
grep -qw -- "$users" "$file1"; in_file1=$?
grep -qw -- "$users" "$file2"; in_file2=$?

case "${in_file1},${in_file2}" in
    0,0) echo found in both files ;;
    0,*) echo only in file1 ;;
    *,0) echo only in file2 ;;
      *) echo in neither file ;;
esac
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the optional way. It works enough well!! works perfectly in another script I have.

Comment: That's a great idea! Always learning.

Answer (score 8):

```
n=0

#Or if you have more files to check, you can put your while here. 
grep -qw -- "$users" "$file1" && ((n++))
grep -qw -- "$users" "$file2" && ((n++))

case $n in 
   1) 
       echo "Only one file with the string"
    ;;
   2)
       echo "The two files are with the string"
   ;;
   0)
       echo "No one file with the string"
   ;;
   *)
       echo "Strange..."
   ;;
esac
```

Note: `((n++))` is a ksh extension (also supported by `zsh` and `bash`). In POSIX `sh` syntax, you'd need `n=$((n + 1))` instead.

Comment: Oh sorry i was typing $((n++)) instead of ((n++)). Forget.

Comment: Note that `n=$((n++))` will NEVER change the value of n because `n++` is **post** increment: it returns the *current value* of n, then increments n; then you set the variable to the returned value which was the original n.

Comment: If you can assume your filenames don't contain newlines, `local IFS=$'\n'; matches=( $(grep -lw "$users" "$file1" "$file2") )`, and use `case "${#matches[@]" in`.  @glenn: this idea applies to your answer, too, to avoid multiple invocations of `grep`.  Piping it to `grep -l | wc -l` would also work.

Comment: @Peter that would be worth writing up as a separate answer IMO.

Comment: @StephenKitt: I wasn't going to because I couldn't find a bulletproof way to handle arbitrary filename characters.  But since you think it's worth it, I wrote it up anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If your filenames don't contain newlines, you can avoid multiple invocations of `grep` by having grep print the names of matching files, and count the results.

```
 local IFS=$'\n'    # inside a function.  Otherwise use some other way to save/restore IFS
 matches=( $(grep -lw "$users" "$file1" "$file2") )
```

The number of matches is `"${#matches[@]}"`.

**There might be a way to use `grep --null -lw` here, but I'm not sure how to parse the output**.  Bash `var=( array elements )` don't have a way to use a `\0` delimiter instead of `\n`.  Maybe bash's `mapfile` builtin can do it?  But probably not, because you specify the delimiter with `-d string`.

---

You could `count=$(grep -l | wc -l)`, but then you have two external processes so you might as well just run `grep` on the two files separately.  (The difference between `grep` vs. `wc` startup overhead is small compared to fork+exec + dynamic linker stuff to start up a separate process at all).

Also, with `wc -l` you don't find out *which* file matched.

---

With the results captured in an array, that might already be what you want, or if there's exactly 1 match, you can check if it was the first input or not.

```
local IFS=$'\n'    # inside a function.  Otherwise use some other way to save/restore IFS
matches=( $(grep -lw "$users" "$file1" "$file2") )

# print the matching filenames
[[ -n $matches ]] && printf  'match in %s\n'  "${matches[@]}"

# figure out which input position the name came from, if there's exactly 1.
if [[ "${#matches[@]" -eq 1 ]]; then
    if [[ $matches == "$file1" ]];then
        echo "match in file1"
    else
        echo "match in file2"
    fi
fi
```

`$matches` is shorthand for `${matches[0]}`, the first array element.

Comment: @StephenKitt: I meant `-z`, not `-0`, oops.  Yes that would get grep to print the filenames separated by `\0` like I already mentioned in the answer, but how can you get *bash* to parse that?  You can't set `IFS=$'\0'`, or basically do anything else with `find -print0` style output directly with bash.

Comment: Yes, I read too fast, missing that paragraph, and didn’t think things through (which is why I deleted my comment). There might well be a way, but I can’t think of one just now, and as you say it’s not worth making the solution too complex when there are just a few `grep`s to deal with anyway.

Comment: `mapfile -d $'\0'` sort of works, but it replaces the newlines with spaces (I haven’t tried tweaking `IFS`).